# alert every 5 count

Tags: javascript, loops, alert

Good day, My question is, how to create a javascript alert for this scenario:

I have "5" as a number that adds 1 every minute, now, how would I create an alert when the "5" becomes "10" and becomes "15", basically when +5 on it.

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: So what did you try? Classic do my homework.

Comment: the for loop? just don't know how to place it correctly

Comment: So what did you try that did not work? Post your attempt(s)

Comment: What do you mean by "alert"? A message displayed within the page? You mentioned in a comment about a for loop, but you shouldn't be using a for loop to do time-based updates like changing a value every minute.

Comment: it is like this. my number starts at "7", for example. Then plus 5, it would be like: 8.. 9.. 10.. 11.. 12.. then there is the alert. and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if the value is divisible by 5 and the remainder is 0. Also here in the below example i have added 1 second, you need to change it as 5 minutes..

**DEMO**

```js
var val = 5;
window.setInterval(
function () {
    val = val + 1;
    if(val%5 ==0){
      alert('boom');
    }
    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = "You have " + val + "!";
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="show"></div>
```

Comment: how if it is "+5" not necessarily divisible by 5?

Comment: add else part there

Comment: how? 
for example my number starts at "6" the alert should be in "11". adds 5 to it. not being divisible by 5

Comment: you need to think about a generic logic then.

Comment: hmm. ok, i hope this will made somehow simple. It is like: for every additional 5 (or 3, or even 4) to a number, pops out the alert

Comment: yeah! but that wont be a perfect solution

Comment: it is like this. my number starts at "7", for example. 
Then plus 5, it would be like: 
8.. 9.. 10.. 11.. 12.. then there is the alert. and so on